# Flow diagram Latex Code

Tags: tikz-pgf, flow-charts, automata

Can someone please help with a code that will draw this flow chart diagram in Latex.The image is given the picture below.[image: Compartmental diagram]

Comment: Welcome. // Please take the little burdon to work through one or all 4 tutorials in Part I of https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf and you can draw almost anything from the screenshot.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This site works best if you ask a specific question to a specific problem. I am quite sure that there are already a lot of nice examples for similar diagrams on this site (for example [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/617420/47927) or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/669721/47927)) which you can use as starting points for your diagram. Once you got stuck, show your code. This will make it much easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 2):

While a code showing what has been tried should be posted with such questions, I wanted to play around a bit with the `automata` library.
Here is a solution

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
    \usetikzlibrary{automata}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1cm and 2cm, > = Stealth, accepting/.style = accepting by arrow]

    \node[%
        state, rectangle, fill = red,%
        accepting, accepting text = {$(\mu + \omega_1)\mathrm{A}$}] (A) {A};
    \node[%
        state, rectangle, fill = blue!40!white, above right = of A,%
        initial above, initial text = {$(1 - p)\mu v$},%
        accepting, accepting text = {$\mu\mathrm{E}$}] (E) {E};
    \node[%
        state, rectangle, fill = green, below right = of A,%
        accepting, accepting text = {$\mu\mathrm{Q}$}] (Q) {Q};
    \node[%
        state, rectangle, fill = yellow, below left = of A,
        accepting left, accepting text = {$(\mu + \omega_2)\mathrm{R}$}] (R) {R};
    \node[%
        state, rectangle, fill = green!30!white, above left = of A,%
        initial above, initial text = {$p\mu v$},%
        accepting left, accepting text = {$\mu\mathrm{S}$}] (S) {S};

    \path[->] (A) edge[bend right]  node[above left]            {$\pi\mathrm{A}$}              (R)
              (E) edge              node[above left]            {$\varepsilon\eta\mathrm{EA}$} (A)
              (E) edge              node[right]                 {$\lambda\mathrm{E}$}          (Q)
              (R) edge[bend right]  node[near end, below right] {$\rho\mathrm{R}$}             (A)
              (R) edge              node[below]                 {$\theta\mathrm{R}$}           (Q)
              (S) edge              node[above right]           {$\varepsilon\mathrm{SA}$}     (A)
              (S) edge              node[above]                 {$\gamma\mathrm{S}$}           (E);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

resulting in [image]

Comment: If you set `node distance = 1cm and 2cm` you can then later leave it out from the `… of`s.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks! I wasn't sure of that and did not test. I edited accordingly